# problem with the last terms of uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

i've problem with the last terms of uncertainty principle:
1. are these equalities true:
$$\langle \{\Delta \hat A,\Delta \hat B\} \rangle=\langle \{\hat A, \hat B \}\rangle$$
$$\langle [\Delta \hat A,\Delta \hat B] \rangle=\langle [\hat A, \hat B] \rangle.$$

1. what is result of product commutator with anti commutator?

Comment: If you defined $\Delta \hat{A} = \hat{A} - \langle A \rangle$, then yes, the equalities are true... just use the associativity of the sum; the second question it's some kind of something that is not trivial, and I don't if it really has a physical meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined $\Delta \hat A=\hat A -\langle \hat A \rangle$ and then $\Delta \hat B=\hat B -\langle \hat B \rangle$ **no** , one of the equalities is not true!.
$$\langle \{\Delta \hat A,\Delta \hat B\} \rangle\not=\langle \{\hat A, \hat B \}\rangle$$.

but this one is true:

$$\langle [\Delta \hat A,\Delta \hat B] \rangle=\langle [\hat A, \hat B] \rangle.$$